# Adobe Media Encoder included in After Effects Licence?

Tags: after-effects, adobe, adobe-media-encoder

I currently have an anctive creative cloud licence, but I'm looking to slim down for a while. I actually only need After Effects and the Media Encoder at the moment.

Is the Adobe media encoder included in the single After effects licence? Unfortunately I was unable to find that out on the Adobe support pages. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to encode things, and that would be just dumb. Even though it happens a bit under the hood, all encodings from Premiere Pro and After Effects are handled by Media Encoder. When you install Premiere Pro or After Effects, Media Encoder always gets installed alongside it.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I thought, but I was n't sure if there was some slimed down version of rendering directly in After effects. That used to be so, right, in older versions?

Comment: @EluciusFTW I'm not sure, I mostly use Premiere Pro ... but for CC, all applications that render something pipeline it through Media Encoder